# docker build fails with the below message

Tags: asp.net, docker, nuget

```
[build-env 5/7] RUN dotnet restore:
#12 1.506   Determining projects to restore...
#12 48.75 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.401/NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [/app/OptimizerContainerAPI.csproj]
#12 48.75 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.401/NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [/app/OptimizerContainerAPI.csproj]
#12 48.75 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.401/NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain [/app/OptimizerContainerAPI.csproj]
```

Below is the snippet from my Dockerfile

```
#Get base image for the .Net Core from Microsoft
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as build-env
WORKDIR /app

#copy the CSPROJ files and restore any dependicies
COPY *.csproj ./
COPY NuGet.Config ./
RUN dotnet restore


#Copy the project files and build our release
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


#Generate Runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY  --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "OPTIMIZERCONTAINERAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: Does your docker container have internet access? If so, does the dotnet project reference any private internal NuGet packages, which the container may not have access to?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. The last line of the error is telling you that it's failing to connect because of a certificate validation issue. The server you have configured as the Nuget source is using an invalid certificate for SSL.

Comment: @Ermiya Eskandary : I am able to connect to the internet from my container and my dot net core project does not reference any private nuget feed.

Comment: any update as to possible solution(s) to this issue?